# Implementing AdMob Interstitial Ads in SwiftUI (5) and Xcode (12.4)

Tags: swiftui, admob

I am working on implementing interstitial ads in my app and running into some confusion with the docs provided by AdMob and the new SwiftUI app structure.

Here is the `app.swift` file, showing that I've implemented the GoogleMobileAds and started it in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds
    
@main
struct AdamsCalcApp: App {
    var calculator = Calculator()
        
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(calculator)
        }
    }
}
    
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Setup Google AdMob instance
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        return true
    }
}
```

In my `ContentView.swift` file, I have the interstitial variable created like:

```swift
@State var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?
```

Then, on the main stack in the view, I call `onAppear(perform:)` to load the ad:

```swift
.onAppear(perform: {
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",
                           request: request,
                           completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                               if let error = error { return }
                               interstitial = ad
                               interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                           }
    )
})
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> "Cannot assign value of type 'ContentView' to type 'GADFullScreenContentDelegate?'"

I am feeling a bit clueless after trying a few different workarounds and trying to look up a setup that is like mine. AdMob docs still only show how to implement it with `UIViewController` but I would like to figure out how to do this in SwiftUI.

Comment: Have you searched SO for "SwiftUI interstitial"? There are a number of results that might be useful to you.

Comment: After looking through SwiftUI Interstitial I found the difference that worked for me, I will post the answer below.

Comment: Pls have a look at this gist of Ads in SwiftUI - https://gist.github.com/dhanrajdc7/6442ff07fc27a15b4f062f70b3be2684

Comment: The gist of Ads in SwiftUI is slightly deprecated, the GADInterstitialDelegate is no longer in scope, as well as GADInterstitial.

Answer (score 6):

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport

class AdsManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    private struct AdMobConstant {
        static let interstitial1ID = "..."
    }
    
    final class Interstitial: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate, ObservableObject {

        private var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?
        
        override init() {
            super.init()
            requestInterstitialAds()
        }

        func requestInterstitialAds() {
            let request = GADRequest()
            request.scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
                GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: AdMobConstant.interstitial1ID, request: request, completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    interstitial = ad
                    interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                })
            })
        }
        func showAd() {
            let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
            if let fullScreenAds = interstitial {
                fullScreenAds.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
            } else {
                print("not ready")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
}


class AdsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AdsViewModel()
    @Published var interstitial = AdsManager.Interstitial()
    @Published var showInterstitial = false {
        didSet {
            if showInterstitial {
                interstitial.showAd()
                showInterstitial = false
            } else {
                interstitial.requestInterstitialAds()
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    let adsVM = AdsViewModel.shared
    init() {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(adsVM)
    }
}
```

Toggle the **showInterstitial** parameter in the **AdsViewModel** anywhere in the application and the advertisement will be shown.

Comment: To show the ad: `@EnvironmentObject var adsViewModel: AdsViewModel` and then `adsViewModel.showInterstitial = true`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use AdMob with the newest SwiftUI release, I needed to change `interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self` in `onAppear` to:

```swift
let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
self.interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
```

So, the final code reads:

```swift
.onAppear(perform: {
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",
                           request: request,
                           completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                               if let error = error { return }
                               interstitial = ad
                               let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
                               self.interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
                           }
    )
})
```