# SwiftUI - AdMob Interstitial ad crashes only on iOS 16

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob, interstitial, ios16

I have a view in which there is an interstitial ad that gets presented. On iOS 15 everything works fine, but on iOS 16 the app crashes with the following error:

> SwiftUI/UIViewControllerRepresentable.swift:332: Fatal error:
> UIViewControllerRepresentables must be value types: InterstitialAdView
> 2022-09-22 09:33:06.740743+0200 HowRich[47572:2135353]
> SwiftUI/UIViewControllerRepresentable.swift:332: Fatal error:
> UIViewControllerRepresentables must be value types: InterstitialAdView
> (lldb)

And where there's the @main I get this error:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
InterstitialAdsManager.swift

import GoogleMobileAds
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class InterstitialAd: NSObject {
    var interstitialAd: GADInterstitialAd?
    
    static let shared = InterstitialAd()
    
    func loadAd(withAdUnitId id: String) {
        let req = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: id, request: req) { interstitialAd, err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to load ad with error: \(err)")
                return
            }
            
            self.interstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
    }
}

final class InterstitialAdView: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
    
    let interstitialAd = InterstitialAd.shared.interstitialAd
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var adUnitId: String
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, adUnitId: String) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.adUnitId = adUnitId
        super.init()
        
        interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let view = UIViewController()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1)) {
            self.showAd(from: view)
        }
        
        return view
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func showAd(from root: UIViewController) {
        
        if let ad = interstitialAd {
            ad.present(fromRootViewController: root)
        } else {
            print("Ad not ready")
            self.isPresented.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        InterstitialAd.shared.loadAd(withAdUnitId: adUnitId)
        
        isPresented.toggle()
    }
}

struct FullScreenModifier<Parent: View>: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var adUnitId: String
    var parent: Parent
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            parent
            
            if isPresented {
                EmptyView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                InterstitialAdView(isPresented: $isPresented, adUnitId: adUnitId)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
           InterstitialAd.shared.loadAd(withAdUnitId: adUnitId)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func presentInterstitialAd(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, adUnitId: String) -> some View {
        FullScreenModifier(isPresented: isPresented, adUnitId: adUnitId, parent: self)
    }
}
```

The View with the ad:

```
struct CheckoutView: View {
   
    @State var showAd = false

  var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                  //The view
                   }
                    .onAppear {
            if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AdCounter") == "0" && UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AdFree") == false {
                showAd = true
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue("1", forKey: "AdCounter")
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue("0", forKey: "AdCounter")
         }
        .presentInterstitialAd(isPresented: $showAd, adUnitId: myIntersId)
}
}
}
```

I have updated all pods to the latest available versions (Google Mobile Ads SDK is version 9.11.0).
What's causing the crash on iOS 16 and how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: UiViewcontrollerRepresentsbles need to be a struct. There are better setups for this just search on google. This is a very bad implementation. Watch demystifying SwiftUI all SwiftUI views should always be structs

Comment: I followed this article for the above implementation -> https://medium.com/geekculture/adding-google-mobile-ads-admob-to-your-swiftui-app-in-ios-14-5-5073a2b99cf9

I will follow yours and let you know, thank you

Comment: That is a bad article. Don’t use it a UIViewController representable needs to be a struct. I don’t make tutorials.

Comment: @loremipsum I can't find nothing specific to AdMob and the problem I'm facing... I watched the video but I'm not able to migrate my code and the classes I have to structs... Is there something more specific that I can follow?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806) is the closest thing I can give you. It isn't specific it is very generic.

Comment: I managed to fixed the problem thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236888

Comment: @Pandruz: Can you pls post the changes you made to the code or at least point out the direction of the solution ?

Comment: @Chris I have literally copied and pasted the this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236888/9806105 and now it works. Remember to include .environmentObject(adsVM) as well

Answer (score 4):

> @State var interstitial = InterstitialAd()
> interstitial.showAd()

```
///InterstitialAd.swift
import GoogleMobileAds

class InterstitialAd: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
    var interstitialAd: GADInterstitialAd?
    var unitId: String = "your interstitial unitId"
  
    override init() {
        super.init()
        loadAd()
    }
    
    func loadAd() {
        let req = GADRequest()
        req.scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene

        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: unitId, request: req) { [self] interstitialAd, err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to load ad with error: \(err)")
            }

            self.interstitialAd = interstitialAd
            self.interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
    }
    
    //Presents the ad if it can, otherwise dismisses so the user's experience is not interrupted
    func showAd() {
        if let ad = interstitialAd, let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController {
            ad.present(fromRootViewController: root)
        } else {
            print("Ad not ready")
            self.loadAd()
        }
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        //Prepares another ad for the next time view presented
        self.loadAd()
        print("Ad Closed")
    }
    
    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        print("Ad Error")
        self.loadAd()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to change

```
final class InterstitialAdView: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
```

into

```
struct InterstitialAdView: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
```

Comment: @loremipsum For me no, it's not working like that

Comment: @Pandruz it doesn't, there are many issues with hat line of code. `struct` can't be an  `NSObject` and the`GADFullScreenContentDelegate` requires an `NSObject`, it would be closer if Chris made a `Coordinator` the delegate but still not ideal because you lose the ability to preload the ad and then show it on demand.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work. I had a similar problem with an banner add and there it was sufficient to change class with struct. However my Banner class did not inherit NSObject, it just inherits UIViewControllerRepresentable.