# Solution for the implementation of interstitial ads of admob (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob, interstitial, ios16

Starting with iOS16, there was a problem with the implementation of AdMob interstitial advertising. I am using the SwiftUI framework. I looked at many sources, but unfortunately I did not find a solution. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73810996/swiftui-admob-interstitial-ad-crashes-only-on-ios-16) to on a similar topic, but without a solution. On iOS 15 everything works fine, but on iOS 16 the app crashes with the following error:

> SwiftUI/UIViewControllerRepresentable.swift:332: Fatal error:
> UIViewControllerRepresentables must be value types: InterstitialAdView
> 2022-11-20 15:34:32.811071+0300 MyApp[38437:1156286]
> SwiftUI/UIViewControllerRepresentable.swift:332: Fatal error:
> UIViewControllerRepresentables must be value types: InterstitialAdView

As I understand, to implement the *UIViewControllerRepresentable* protocol, you must use a struct, but the *NSObject* and *GADFullScreenContentDelegate* protocols can only be applied in a class. Question: how can the code be modified to meet the above requirements? I am using the following code (original from [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/adding-google-mobile-ads-admob-to-your-swiftui-app-in-ios-14-5-5073a2b99cf9)):

```
// InterstitialAdView
final class InterstitialAdView: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {

    //Here's the Ad Object we just created
    let interstitialAd = InterstitialAd.shared.interstitialAd
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var adUnitId: String

init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, adUnitId: String) {
    self._isPresented = isPresented
    self.adUnitId = adUnitId
    super.init()

    interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self //Set this view as the delegate for the ad
}

//Make's a SwiftUI View from a UIViewController
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    let view = UIViewController()
    //Show the ad after a slight delay to ensure the ad is loaded and ready to present
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1)) {
        self.showAd(from: view)
    }
    return view
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
}

//Presents the ad if it can, otherwise dismisses so the user's experience is not interrupted
func showAd(from root: UIViewController) {
    if let ad = interstitialAd {
        ad.present(fromRootViewController: root)
    } else {
        self.isPresented.toggle()
    }
}

func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    //Prepares another ad for the next time view presented
    InterstitialAd.shared.loadAd(withAdUnitId: adUnitId)
    //Dismisses the view once ad dismissed
    isPresented.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the class to a struct and put all the delegate code in the coordinator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing AdMob Interstitial Ads in SwiftUI (5) and Xcode (12.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168522/implementing-admob-interstitial-ads-in-swiftui-5-and-xcode-12-4)